# rails range conditions with long decimals

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The following statement returns error `undefined method '%' for #<Hash`

```
Circuit.where([:origin_lon => [@lng_min.to_d..@lng_max.to_d]]).all.to_a
```

origin_lon is defined as a decimal with precision: 15, scale: 10 and is indexed.  The resulting range figures here do have 15 decimals. I initially thought this was due to multiple range conditions, but paring the condition down to a single range, this error pops up.

If the condition is stated as float`.to_f`, the error is appended with tha instance variable `{:origin_lon=>[45.39031097871655..45.415676621283446]}:Hash`

What is the syntactic issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses instead of brackets for range.

```
[1..5].class # Array
(1..5).class # Range
```

Also remove the extra brackets from where():

```
Circuit.where(origin_lon: (@lng_min..@lng_max))
```

And you propably dont need .all and .to_a.

Comment: correct serving of humble pie!  closing parenthesis missing `(origin_lon: (@lng_min..@lng_max)`

Comment: @preciz You don't even need the parenthesis. `Circuit.where(origin_lon: @lng_min..@lng_max)` will just work.

Comment: Yes, `1..5` will be a range without parentheses.